# Print the average of n numbers provided by the user

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;                  //define the type of n numbers
    int array[n];           //define the type of array 
    int sum = 0;            //define and initial the type of sum
    int i;                  //define the type of iterator
    float average = 0.0;    //define the type for average
    
    printf("How many numbers are you going to put? ");    //asks for user input
    scanf("%d", &n);                                        //scans the user input and store it as n
    printf("Enter the numbers: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {                         //for loop to get the sum of n numbers
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    average = sum / i;                              //averages the n numbers
    printf("Average = %.2f", average);              //prints out the average of n numbers
    return 0;
}
```

My code works having all positive and all negative numbers but it has problem when entering a mix positive and negative numbers.

Example: If I enter 40 -5 9, the code does not perform well. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `array[n]` is meaningless if `n` is uninitialized. Move that declaration to after you assign a value to `n`.

Comment: [Debug](https://n9.cl/so77233426) it and find out!

Comment: You don't need the array. Read each number into an ordinary variable and add it to `sum`.

Comment: Comments should explain *why* you're doing something, not what you're doing, which is usually obvious (e.g. "ask for user input")

Comment: As @Barmar suggests, comments should (generally) be used to explain non-obvious reasons for doing things a particular way... the "why" of your code. You can presume that the reader understands the "what" of your code. You can help the reader by giving careful thought to naming variables (as you've done.)

Comment: More properly divide by `n` not `i`.

Comment: There is no need to store the values in an array — or to make the user count ahead of time.  You can read values until EOF and add the read values to the sum, and then print the average.  Of course, that means you'd have to check that `scanf()` is successful, but you should be doing that anyway.  Note that the division will be integer division; the result of the integer division (an integer) will be converted to `float`. —— And I see this is mostly what Chris said in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have two primary issues.

- You have undefined behaviour because `n` is initialized when you declare your variable length array. This can be resolved by moving the declaration of the array *after* `n` is read.
- Secondly, `sum / i` is performing integer arithmetic. You then assign this integer to a `float`. 40 + -5 + 9 is 44, which divided by 3 is 14 by the rules of integer arithmetic. You want to cast your sum to a `float` and *then* assign it to `average`. E.g. `float average = (float)sum / n;`

Other issues:

- The array is unnecessary. You never need the individual numbers after you read them in.
- You're not checking the return value to ensure `scanf` has succeeded and that it's read a suitable number. Note than anything less than `1` would yield undefined behaviour.
- You don't need to declare your variables all at the top of your function. Declare them when you need them. If your compiler doesn't support this, get a newer, better compiler. Related to this, `i` can be scoped to your loop: `n` will work just as well for the division as `I`.
- Barring optimization for memory usage in niche cases, `double` provides much greater accuracy than `float`.

Comment: Note that they almost certainly want to use `double`, not `float`. `float` is mostly a performance optimization when you need to store a bunch of them in half the space, and possibly get some greater vectorization. But for 99.9% of cases, the extra precision is worth more than a trivial performance benefit; people are using `float` because they're told about "floating point" and it's easier to remember `float`, but `double` is what they really wanted. In this case, if the inputs sum to anything above ~8 million, conversion to `float` will lose data *before* dividing, while `double` would not.